# How to set custom name for Exported Excel file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, export-to-excel, xls

I have this JS code which perfectly exports excel. I have tried various ways so that it will take custom names for the files. Currently, its always taking `download.xls` as default file name. Any idea on how to set custom filename in this code? Thanks in advance.

```
function Export()
    {
        var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
        var textRange; var j = 0;
        tab = document.getElementById('TicketTable'); // id of table

        for (j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) {
            tab_text = tab_text + tab.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";
        }

        tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
        tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");//remove if u want links in your table
        tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, ""); // remove if u want images in your table
        tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // reomves input params

        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

        if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
        {
            txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
            txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
            txtArea1.document.close();
            txtArea1.focus();
            sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "SubmittedBilling.xls");
        }
        else 
            //other browser not tested on IE 11
            sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
        return (sa);
    }
```

Comment: But note that what you are saving is not an xls file... It's just HTML markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this after you are done with your `tab_text`.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
a.href = data_type + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text);
a.download = fileName + '.xls';
a.click();
```

**Example:**

```js
var filename = "SomeFileName"
var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr>";
var textRange;
var j = 0;
tab = document.getElementById('table-excel');

for (j = 0; j < tab.rows.length; j++) {
  tab_text = tab_text + tab.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";
}

tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
var a = document.createElement('a');
var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
a.href = data_type + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text);
a.download = filename + '.xls';
a.click();
```

```html
<table id="table-excel">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Works for me!! Thanks..

Comment: i noticed that this code is not working in IE. any idea why?

Comment: Yes, for some reason the snippet itself is not working in IE.. says `HTTPS security is compromised` @shreyPav